# In IDE Rider how could one write template/script that generates file from another file?

Tags: ide

In my project, I often needs to create a `View` file(.xaml) after creating a `ViewModel`(.cs)

If possible I'd like to automate this process, by auto generating the `SomeView.xaml` from `SomeViewModel.cs`

How could one possibly achieve this? Tried using file template but it is not exactly what I want(in a sense it is not generating file from another file)

Comment: Are you asking about [macros](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Using_Macros_in_the_Editor.html)?

Comment: @tuskiomi I had a quick check, it seems to me that macros could not allow customizable namespace(there will be a part in the xaml that would use the ViewModel's namespace)